# Unit Testing for concurrent requests in web application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency

I am working on a web application which is accessed by many concurrent users. I am using MVC 4 and my action method in a controller will call a manager class and get the data from database using Entity Framework. Also, some times the data will be refined using LINQ and send back the result to Action method. This whole process takes 2-3 seconds, and within this time one or more requests can come before the first one finish it.

Now, I need to write a unit test to simulate the above test case and confirm that my code is working.

Please suggest, if any improvement in the application design for concurrent users case.

Thank you Dennis for clarifying the difference between unit-testing and load testing. I am not looking for any tool, I want to re-create the scenario using Visual Studio though unit test methods (if possible). As you have mentioned,

> When you want to know how you code deals with high load, you need load
>   test with real dependencies (e.g., real database instead of fake
>   implementation for unit test).

Is it not possible test without real dependencies ?

Comment: This is not unit-testing, but load testing/integration testing. Unit testing is when you take a piece of code ("unit", usually this is some class), mocking its external dependencies and testing implemented logic, assuming, that you don't care about performance. When you want to know how you code deals with high load, you need load test with real dependencies (e.g., real database instead of fake implementation for unit test). Anyway, your question is unclear - do you looking for a tool, asking for best practice or something else?